# Google don't index my site with sitemap.xml

Tags: sitemap

I have problem with indexing my website. I have sent to google my website sitemap and google was delete all indexed sites. My sitemap is here: [enter link description here](http://errors.win/sitemap.xml)

What is wrong with this sitemap?

Comment: Try this: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ good luck

Comment: Not sure if Google cares, but your XML document is being returned with a text/html ContentType instead of text/xml or application/xml.

Comment: @Rick so Ho can I fix this?